# not reachable from within my own network through outside facing interface

Tags: router, internet, local, external-ip

Is there  any quick answer that lapses me by to this situation -

my server is accssible at 192.168.2.200:5222 without a  problem (from within the local network of course) but if I try to reach it from within the local network through the ISP provided public IP address 92.80.109.173:5222 it times out... Needless to say, from outside my local home network 92.80.109.173:5222 is working just fine. I bet there is something trivial in the middle! But what ?

Thanks

Comment: What type of firewall/router do you have?  You need to make it support [hairpin' NAT](http://serverfault.com/search?q=hairpin+nat).  This is simply impossible on some equipment.

Comment: It is an Edimax something. Nothing fancy, and it's the first time I hear this 'hairpin' word together with NAT. I'll google on it.

Comment: Click the link that I provided, there are many similar questions here.  I suspect you are out of luck though, given what I see on the Edimax pages.  It appears to have a relatively limited level of functionality.

Comment: maybe so, anyway the answer is correct, so you could turn it into an proper answer

Answer (score -2):

You need to setup port forwarding on your router and forward that port number to your internal IP.